# Help Needed! -- Left-Click Function (mouse AND trackpad) Randomly Stops Working

Tags: 18.04, mouse, touchpad, dell, multi-touch

Dell Latitude E7440 i7-4600U. Ubuntu 18.4 LTS.

Semi-non-techie (mid-level novice), new Linux user (~2 months), layperson here.

I have no idea why it happens, but sometimes the left-click functionality of both my mouse and trackpad (both trackpad left-click button, and trackpad finger tap/double-tap simulating a left-click) mysteriously stops working. Seems to be completely randomly, I can't figure out any rhyme or reason why.

Seems like the only way I can restore function is to restart or kill all processes and log out (ctl+alt+backspace) then log back in again.

This only started about 1 or 2 weeks ago, seemingly out of nowhere or no reason why, completely randomly. I have no idea why it started (and continues) failing out of the blue. Sometimes it will happen several times within 20-60 minutes, other times I can go several hours without it happening. Seldom now will it go as long as a full day without failing at least once.

It's getting pretty annoying and frustrating. Any help/thoughts/advice of any kind is greatly appreciated.